# Flyway only migrates one of my two configured schemas

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, flyway

I have a MySQL 5.7 instance that needs to have two DBs with identical schemas.  I'm trying to use flyway with multiple schemas to accomplish this.  I'm using the Maven plugin and v5.1.38 of the MySQL connector.  Here is my POM config:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306</url>
                        <user>root</user>
                        <password>mypassword</password>
                        <schemas>
                            <schema>stage</schema>
                            <schema>public</schema>
                        </schemas>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Running from an empty DB, this is the output:

```
[INFO] Database: jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306 (MySQL 5.7)
[INFO] Successfully validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.013s)
[INFO] Creating schema `stage` ...
[INFO] Creating schema `public` ...
[INFO] Creating Metadata table: `stage`.`schema_version`
[INFO] Current version of schema `stage`: 0
[INFO] Migrating schema `stage` to version 1 - initialize schema
[INFO] Migrating schema `stage` to version 2 - seed users
[INFO] Migrating schema `stage` to version 3 - create read items proc
[WARNING] DB: PROCEDURE stage.read_items does not exist (SQL State: 42000 - Error Code: 1305)
[INFO] Successfully applied 3 migrations to schema `stage` (execution time 00:01.824s).
```

It creates both schemas, but then only runs the migrations for the first one.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Flyway?

**Update:**

I've tried to create two executions for the Maven plugin using this config:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>migrate-stage</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>migrate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/stage</url>
                                <user>root</user>
                                <password>password</password>
                                <schemas>
                                    <schema>stage</schema>
                                </schemas>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>migrate-pub</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>migrate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/public</url>
                                <user>root</user>
                                <password>password</password>
                                <schemas>
                                    <schema>public</schema>
                                </schemas>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

That gives me the following error:

```
Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the answer I was hoping for, but having tried everything else, I wound up just duplicating the SQL for the 2nd schema, adding a `use public;` or `use stage;` before the respective part.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be similar to the following : [Flyway database migration to multiple schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546313/flyway-database-migration-to-multiple-schemas) 
As Mr. Fontaine suggest you should split your schema's for this scenario.
I'm not certain about the correct usage of the schema-tag as I'm new to Flyway myself.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I did take a look at that answer, and tried to create separate executions in Maven.  I've updated my question with the results of that effort.

Comment: Looks correct though I think a goal tag should be added to you execution block. The goal should express migrate for your scenario.

Comment: Oops - updated to reflect that I've added the goal also.  Same error message.  I also experimented with every combination of including the schema name in the url and in the schemas config.  No luck.