# migrate changes to multiple schemas

Tags: database-migration, flyway

The way our database is designed, we have a different schema designated to different clients. So each DDL change needs to be applied to each schema. At the same time, when we roll out changes, we want to control which schemas get the changes in that particular migration. Essentially we want to migrate changes to a few clients and then in a few days time roll out the same changes to the remaining schema.

I can write my DDL changes with a placeholder for schema_name and this resolves the  dynamic schema issue. But I can only pass in one replacement string at a time. Is there a way to pass in multiple values/array of strings for a replacement placeholder?

Secondly is there a way to run the same migration multiple times but with different values for the replacement placeholder?

Comment: This seems to address this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546313/flyway-database-migration-to-multiple-schemas#27588444